# install ubuntu in Lenovo T460p with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo laptop T460P installed with Windows 7 64 bits. Now I hit a problem  trying to install ubuntu to dual-boot.

**The guide**
I'm following the approach at https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653 , except, since I had problem restarting, in step 5, I chose "Do something else" to select the target installation. So I downloaded ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso and build the usb start up drive.

**The machine seen in Windows** has 2 harddisks, in Windows I can run `diskmgmt.msc` to check Windows Partition, it shows:

disk 0, Basic (465.64GB) online

- 100MB Healthy (EFI System Partition)
- Windows7_OS (D:) 452.17 GB NTFS, Healthy (Primary Partition)
- Lenovo_Recovery (E:) 13.37 GB NTFS, Healthy (Primary Partition)

disk 1, Basic (238.35 GB) online

- 69 MB, Healthy (EFI System Partition)
- Windows7_OS (C:), 178.53 GB NTFS, Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)
- 1 MB, Healthy (Primary Partition)
- 49.15 GB, Healthy (Primary Partition) >> this is the partition I split out by `diskmgmt.msc` to install Ubuntu, following the *guide*'s step 2 "Create space on your hard drive by Shrinking Windows."
- Lenovo_Recovery (Q:), 10.60 GB NTFS, Healthy (Primary Partition)

disk 2, Removable 28.64 GB, online

- UUI (F:), 28.64 GB FAT32, Healthy (Active, Primary Partition) >> this is the usb drive

**The machine seen in Ubuntu**, as in step 5 of the *guide* 'Run the installer', in the "Installation type" window, I can see the partitions are listed as:

/dev/sda  >> this shall be Windows disk 0

- free space, 1 MB
- /dev/sda1, fat32, 104 MB
- /dev/sda2, 134 MB
- /dev/sda3, ntfs, 485510 MB >> this shall be Windows D: drive
- /dev/sda4, ntfs, 14357 MB  >> this shall be Windows E: drive
- free space, 0 MB

/dev/sdb  >> this shall be Windows disk 1

- free space, 1 MB
- /dev/sdb1, fat32, 72 MB
- /dev/sdb2, 134 MB
- /dev/sdb3, ntfs, 191693 MB, windows 7  >> this shall be Windows C: drive
- free space, 0 MB
- /dev/sdb5, biosgrub, 1 MB
- /dev/sdb6, ext4 >> this shall be the free space I created
- /dev/sdb4, ntfs, 11383 MB
- free space, 2MB

**Installation Type**, in this windows I select /dev/sdb6, change it as

- size = 52770 MB
- Use as: ext4 journaling file system
- Checked "format the partition:
- mount point = /

The under "Device for boot loader installation", I can see:

- /dev/sda ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (500.1 GB)
- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sda3
- /dev/sda4
- /dev/sdb ATA TS256GMTS400 (256.1 GB) --- select this then
- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdb3 Windows 7
- /dev/sdb6
- /dev/sdb4

I selected `dev/sdb`, it comes a warning: "The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #6 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdb) as ext4". After click continue, the installation completed without warning.

**The problem**: installation finished, then I restarted the laptop, without the USB stick, it always goes to Windows 7 start up, not as described in the *guide* that "When your computer reboots a menu should appear with options for Windows and Ubuntu."

If i press F1 at start up and enter the T460P motherboard set up, it shows

1. USD HDD
2. ATA HDD1 TS256GMTS400
3. Windows Boot Manager
4. ATA HDD0 TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0
5. USB CD
6. USB FDD
7. NVMe0
8. PCI LAN IBA CL Slot 00FE v0105

I tried change this to

1. ATA HDD1 TS256GMTS400
2. Windows Boot Manager

or

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. ATA HDD1 TS256GMTS400

but to no avail -- I see nothing as to choose windows or ubuntu, it always goes to the Windows login screen.

What shall I do?

Comment: Surprisingly you have Windows 7 installed in UEFI mode. Ubuntu should have been installed the same buy it wasn't. The guide isn't applicable because it assumes BIOS.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don’t quite understand UEFI, seems https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/ says UEFI is a replacement of BIOS ... So you mean the guide only works for BIOS? then what can i do to have a dual boot? Does this guide https://tothepoles.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/lenovo-t470p-ubuntu-16-04-install-notes/ work?

Comment: Make sure you're booting the installer in UEFI mode (you probably noticed tbe USB listed twice). You can then "Try Ubuntu" and in tha live session, open GParted, select the drive where you installed, remove `sdb5` and `sdb6`. Tben start the installer amd choose install alongside and the correct drive.

Comment: I don't understand: "booting the installer in UEFI mode" -- what does it mean? I did boot successfully using the usb installer, and entered Ubuntu then clicked short cut "Install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS" to install Ubuntu.

Comment: When you booted the USB didn't you see it twice in the list, one of the entries with UEFI in the name?Also how did you made that USB? UEFI is what replaced BIOS a long time ago, by the way.

Comment: I made the USB according to the guide: "The easiest way to create a bootable USB drive for non UEFI drives is to download the Universal USB Installer ( https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ )." --  Oh! does this mean the USB drive is not correct as it is for non UEFI?

Comment: Exactly. In Windows you may use Rufus in dd mode or with settings to UEFI / GPT before burning the ISO. Alternatively, just format the USB as FAT32, open the ISO with 7Zip (or any other similar tool) and extract to the USB, then in Disk Management mark the partition with a boot flag.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia during restarting laptop, I pressed F1 to enter the ThinkPad Set up, in Startup > Boot, I see the Bott Priority Order as 1. USB HDD SanDisk Ultra (this is the bootable USB), 2. Windows Boot manager, 3. ATA HDD1 TS256GMTS400, 4. ATA HDD0 TOSHIBA MQ01ACF050, 5. USB CD, 6. USB FDD, 7. NVMe0, 8. PCI LAN IBA CL Slot 00FE v0105. Is this as expected?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia OK I'll try Rufus to build the USB bootable again -- the guide points to https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ , which is using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.8.7.exe

Comment: In setup tru to find a setting about UEFI, CSM  or Legacy. Since Windows 7 is already in UEFI mode, disable CSM/Legacy, set to "UEFI only" or something similar (it varies with brand and model). This assures the USB will boot in the correct mode.

Comment: More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi (ignore it being about Windows 8/10, the different mode is what matters)

Comment: According to the webs it's in the Boot menu ＞Boot Mode. Here make sure it's UEFI only (and prepare a that can boot in UEFI mode) and you should be good to go. :)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia ok i've modified in ThinkPad Setup to "UEFI only".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thank! I got both Ubuntu and Win7 now! Looks UEFI and Rufus are the tricks. thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad my limited knowledge was useful to someone :)